# How should I attach a image to border-bottom?

Tags: css, canvas, twitter-bootstrap-3

http://bootply.com/89567

I attached a pattern to the `border-bottom`, since there isn't a specific `borde-image` selector for that, I've  used `:after` to attach it. However the image doesn't scale with the rest.

Should I maybe create the border pattern in canvas? How could I accomplish that?

Thanks in advance

```
.redbrd {
    height: 400px;
    width: auto;
    background: #D20000;
}

.redbrd:after {
    content: url("http://i.imgur.com/iKXPOF0.png");
    position: relative;
    top: 400px;
}
```

```
<section class="col-md-12">
                <div class="row">
                    <article class="col-md-6">

                    </article>

                    <article class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6">
                                <div class="redbrd"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6">
                                <div class="redbrd"></div>
                            </div>
                    </article>
                </div>
            </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add border-image property for the div. And disable all the border except bottom border.
eg:

```
div
{
-webkit-border-image:url(border.png) 30 30 round; /* Safari 5 */
-o-border-image:url(border.png) 30 30 round; /* Opera */
border-image:url(border.png) 30 30 round;
border-top:0px;
border-left:0px;
border-right:0px;

}
```

Or try this

```
 div
  {
      border-image-slice: 0 0 27 0; border-image-width: 20px 20px 20px 20px; 
      border-image-      outset: 0px 0px 0px 0px; border-image-repeat: stretch stretch;
     border-image-source: url("https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/6007/border-image-1.png");
        }
```

I think this link will be helpful for you **https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Tools/Border-image_generator**
.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.redbrd:after {
     content: " ";
     position: relative;
     top: 400px;
     display: block;
     background: url("http://i.imgur.com/iKXPOF0.png") repeat-x;
     height: 30px;
}
```